# Problem with Pearson correlation coefficient.

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

I have two random variables X and Y. X follows a power law distribution. I know its generating function G(x). I also know the Pearson correlation coefficient of X and Y. How do I find the generating function of Y?

Comment: I know Y is also a power law distribution function

Comment: Closed. See Douglas' comment, which answers your question.

Comment: Since Douglas's comment is gone, let me add that the answer in it was "To answer your question, you can't in general, as you have 1 condition on an infinite dimensional space."